# Adding a header name to a group of columns in a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header, multiple-columns

I have dataframe in a format which is shown as below:

```
Product       R_1     R_2      R_3      S_1     S_2      S_3
x            2       4       21        12      43       54
y            5       2       12        42     31       12
```

Now I want to club columns R_1, R_2 and R_3 and assign them under header Store_R while similarly combine columns S_1, S_2 and S_3 under header Store_S, such that the output is now in the format shown below:

```
              Store_R                Store_S
Product    R_1     R_2      R_3     S_1     S_2       S_3
x         2       4       21      12      43         54
y         5       2       12      42      31         12
```

Answer (score 6):

You can [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) filtered `Dataframes` by [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
#if Product is column set to index
df = df.set_index('Product')
print (pd.concat([df.filter(like='R'), 
                  df.filter(like='S')],  
                  axis=1,  
                  keys=('Store_R','Store_S')))

        Store_R         Store_S        
            R_1 R_2 R_3     S_1 S_2 S_3
Product                                
x             2   4  21      12  43  54
y             5   2  12      42  31  12
```

Another solution with creating [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) but is necessary first columns are all `R` and then `S`. Because values are assigned and is possible some values can be wrong aligned.

```
colsR = [('Store_R', col) for col in df.columns if 'R' in col]
colsS = [('Store_S', col) for col in df.columns if 'S' in col]

df = df.set_index('Product')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(colsR + colsS)
print (df)
        Store_R         Store_S        
            R_1 R_2 R_3     S_1 S_2 S_3
Product                                
x             2   4  21      12  43  54
y             5   2  12      42  31  12
```

[`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) can help sort column names:

```
print (df)
  Product  S_1  R_2  R_3  S_12  S_2  S_3
0       x    2    4   21    12   43   54
1       y    5    2   12    42   31   12

colsR = [('Store_R', col) for col in df.columns if 'R' in col]
colsS = [('Store_S', col) for col in df.columns if 'S' in col]

df = df.set_index('Product').sort_index(axis=1)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(colsR + colsS)
print (df)
        Store_R     Store_S             
            R_2 R_3     S_1 S_12 S_2 S_3
Product                                 
x             4  21       2   12  43  54
y             2  12       5   42  31  12
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. But what if the value for the number of stores is dynamic. Currently I have mentioned only two stores R and S, let's assume now I am having 15 such stores with me and I want to put the same type of header for the same.